# How to \ExecuteOptions that are handled by \DeclareOption*?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm writing a class file based on the report class, for which I want the default font size to be 12 pt rather than 10 pt.  I tried specifying a default font size using the `\ExecuteOptions{}` command, but it didn't work the way I expected.  Here's a simple example:

testclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023-02-07 Test class]

% All options passed to report class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

% Execute options with default values
\ExecuteOptions{12pt}

% Process options
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Load base class
\LoadClass{report}

% etc.
```

testdoc.tex

```
\documentclass{testclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

But when I run this code, the font size remains at 10pt instead of 12pt.  When I wrote the `\ExecuteOptions{12pt}` command, I was expecting it to execute the code inside `\DeclareOption*{}` since that is how all options given by the user to the class are handled.  But apparently that doesn't apply to options specified through other means, like `\ExecuteOptions{}`.

**Is there some way to make `\ExecuteOptions{}` able to execute the code in `\DeclareOption*{}`?**

(Note: It works if you specifically add a `\DeclareOption{12pt}{}`, but it's not very practical to write a declaration for every possible default option you might want.)

Comment: Why do you use (or want to use) that indirection? Just use `\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{report}` instead of `\ExecuteOption` for an option you never defined.

Comment: @Skillmon That works for this particular problem, but there may be other cases where the code in `\DeclareOption*` is more extensive and doesn't just involve passing options to another class.  It would be good to have a way to execute that code the way you can execute code in an unstarred `\DeclareOption`.

Comment: In that case use a more sophisticated solution than the default option handling. For instance `\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}\ekvdefinekeys{testclass}{unknown noval = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}\ekvset{testclass}{12pt}\ekvoUseUnknownHandlers*\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{testclass}` (disclaimer: I'm the author of `expkv` and friends).

Comment: oh, or use the new key=value based build in option handling (see `ltnews35.pdf` for a short documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop used in `\ExecuteOptions` is pretty simple and doesn't use any code to check for an existing option whatsoever. You can use the following instead that will check for a defined option and use the fallback option instead:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{testclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023-02-07 Test class]

% All options passed to report class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\newcommand*\ExecuteOptionsOrUseFallback[1]{%
  \edef\@fortmp{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
  \def\reserved@a##1\@nil{%
    \@for\CurrentOption:=\@fortmp\do
            {\@ifundefined{ds@\CurrentOption}%
                {\default@ds}%
                {\csname ds@\CurrentOption\endcsname}}%
    \edef\CurrentOption{##1}}%
  \expandafter\reserved@a\CurrentOption\@nil}

% Execute options with default values
\ExecuteOptionsOrUseFallback{12pt}

% Process options
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Load base class
\LoadClass{report}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{testclass}

\begin{document}
This is in size: \makeatletter\f@size pt\makeatother.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that will do the trick.  I had to do a bit of research to understand all that code, but I think I've figured it out, except for one thing: what does \@nil mean / do?

Comment: @Frink `\@nil` does nothing. It's just used to right-delimit the argument to `\@reserved@a`. This is the same code that `\ExecuteOptions` uses, except for the contents of the `\@for`-loop, in that one I've added the `\@ifundefined`-check and the call to `\default@ds`, the (current) kernel's implementation just uses `\csname ds@\CurrentOption\endcsname`.